# Read csv files and calculate the total sum

Tags: csv, python-3.x

```
import glob
import csv

def read_with_csv(filename):
    data = []
    for x in csv.reader(open(filename, 'r')):
        data.append(x)            
    return data 

def calculate_sum(data_sample):
    total = 0
    for row in data_sample[1:]:
        price = float(row[9])
        total += price
    return total

files = [file for file in glob.glob("*.csv") if 'Invoice-Item-Adjustment_' in file]
data_from_csv = read_with_csv(files)
the_sum = data_from_csv(calculate_sum)
print(the_sum)
```

I have multiple files in directory and read to list and loop through the amount in the column and telly up the monthly total sum. I have erros and not sure how to deal with.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "listing.py", line 18, in <module>
        data_from_csv = read_with_csv(files)
      File "listing.py", line 6, in read_with_csv
        for x in csv.reader(open(filename, 'r')):
    TypeError: invalid file: ['JEExport_20141201-20141218_Invoice-Item-Adjustment_20
    150208164027.csv', 'JEExport_20150116-20150128_Invoice-Item-Adjustment_201502021
    70516.csv'

]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions in python would return a collection  - not the file itself.

Hence

```
files = [file for file in glob.glob("*.csv") if 'Invoice-Item-Adjustment_' in file]
```

returns a list of files whose names contain **Invoice-Item-Adjustment**. You would have to iterate through the files one by one and then process it.

Comment: got it working. currently i 2 files there but its given me one total per file. I want to combine to one file with one total.  \C:>python listing.py
32925.46
37701.64

Comment: files = [file for file in glob.glob("*.csv") if 'Invoice-Item-Adjustment_' in file]
for afile in files:
    data_from_csv= read_with_csv(afile)
    the_sum= calculate_sum(data_from_csv)
    print(the_sum)

Comment: @RicardLe What I understand is that you want to combine the totals of all files into one single total. Am I correct? If yes, then maintain a variable say all_total variable initialized to 0 which would store the running total for all the CSV files that have been processed ( all_total += calculate_sum(data_from_csv)). When all your files are processes all_total will hold the total sum

Comment: that is correct. i have got the running total computed. many thanks

Comment: Hi Prahalad, i don't a see button to accept your answer. I think a novice don't have that options ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function read_with_csv() takes a filename as an argument NOT a list of files. So instead, the following might work depending on what you want to do exactly

```
data_from_csv = [read_with_csv(file) for file in files]
```